# Apply system settings with javafx

Tags: javafx, settings, system, apply

With Java Swing I can take over system settings with the help of look and feel. z. For example, large system fonts or another color scheme. 
how is that with javafx?

barrier-free greetings

Markus

Answer (score 2):

In JavaFX, look and feel are achieved by CSS styling. Look and feel are independent of the System (i.e. Operating System).

There are two main ways to do this.

#### User Agent Stylesheet

This is the more flexible option that is great for applying Application-wide styling. By default, JavaFX engine will load an agent stylesheet for you depending on the JavaFX version. For JavaFX 2.x, the "caspian" stylesheet will be loaded, and for JavaFX 8.0 and later, the "modena" stylesheet will be loaded.

To use this option, you can copy from one of these two stylesheets. You can get a copy from jfxrt.jar (JAR file for JavaFX API), or search for it online. You can then proceed to modify from that base stylesheet.

#### Adding stylesheet to root nodes

Alternatively, you can create a stylesheet which you would load into each root node of every `Scene`. The advantage of this option is that you will only need to change a few properties that you need. This is because JavaFX will apply the "caspian" or "modena" stylesheet before applying yours.

This method is easier if you have only one (or very little) window/scene. It can become troublesome if your application needs to spawn a lot of windows. If you do not set the stylesheet in one window, it will apply the default style provided by the "caspian" or "modena" theme.